# Fail in including private package from bitbucket in NPM package.json

Tags: npm, bitbucket, npm-install, package.json

I have set up a bitbucket and also add the App Password with all permissions.

but, when I install the package, I got the followings:

```
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *: usage: git rev-list [OPTION] <commit-id>... [ -- paths... ]
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:   limiting output:
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --max-count=<n>
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --max-age=<epoch>
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --min-age=<epoch>
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --sparse
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --no-merges
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --min-parents=<n>
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --no-min-parents
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --max-parents=<n>
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --no-max-parents
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --remove-empty
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --all
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --branches
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --tags
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --remotes
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --stdin
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --quiet
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:   ordering output:
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --topo-order
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --date-order
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --reverse
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:   formatting output:
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --parents
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --children
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --objects | --objects-edge
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --unpacked
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --header | --pretty
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --abbrev=<n> | --no-abbrev
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --abbrev-commit
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --left-right
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --count
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:   special purpose:
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --bisect
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --bisect-vars
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *:     --bisect-all
npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 *: 
npm ERR! Darwin 17.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "git+https://murvinlai:CgCWEhhGYJ69v3gXA5k5@bitbucket.org/chasingsunrise/database-model.git#*" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code 129

npm ERR! Command failed: git rev-list -n1 *
npm ERR! usage: git rev-list [OPTION] <commit-id>... [ -- paths... ]
npm ERR!   limiting output:
npm ERR!     --max-count=<n>
npm ERR!     --max-age=<epoch>
npm ERR!     --min-age=<epoch>
npm ERR!     --sparse
npm ERR!     --no-merges
npm ERR!     --min-parents=<n>
npm ERR!     --no-min-parents
npm ERR!     --max-parents=<n>
npm ERR!     --no-max-parents
npm ERR!     --remove-empty
npm ERR!     --all
npm ERR!     --branches
npm ERR!     --tags
npm ERR!     --remotes
npm ERR!     --stdin
npm ERR!     --quiet
npm ERR!   ordering output:
npm ERR!     --topo-order
npm ERR!     --date-order
npm ERR!     --reverse
npm ERR!   formatting output:
npm ERR!     --parents
npm ERR!     --children
npm ERR!     --objects | --objects-edge
npm ERR!     --unpacked
npm ERR!     --header | --pretty
npm ERR!     --abbrev=<n> | --no-abbrev
npm ERR!     --abbrev-commit
npm ERR!     --left-right
npm ERR!     --count
npm ERR!   special purpose:
npm ERR!     --bisect
npm ERR!     --bisect-vars
npm ERR!     --bisect-all
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/murvinlai/Documents/Projects/side/damn-early-days/npm-debug.log
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Is this the complete log, or is there any entry before this?

Comment: I include this in package.json. And also try npm install.  git+https://murvinlai:CgCWEhhGYJ69v3gXA5k5@bitbucket.org/chasingsunrise/database-model.git#*

Comment: And that is the full log

Answer (score 0):

I found out what's wrong.   because it is a new repo, i didn't set up the version yet. so, if I put #* at the end of the link, it will fail.   I just need to either remove it, or set the right version, and that will be solved. :)